# Can we force the Dart Garbage Collector?

Tags: dart, garbage-collection

I am trying to simulate a Memory Leak for `Streams` (for educational purposes), but I can't be sure memory is actually leaking if the GC hasn't run yet.

Can I force a GC sweep in a pure Dart test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it from the Dart DevTools Web GUI.
https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools

### Updated with example of using vm_service package

With newer Dart versions, we can use the `dart:developer` API to communicate with the Dart VM. This is also how the new [Dart DevTools](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools) are getting data from the VM and make operations like triggering the garbage collector which you can still do manually by going into the web interface.

If you want to trigger this from the code itself, you can do that using the [`vm_service`](https://pub.dev/packages/vm_service) package which makes it easy to interact with the API from the Dart VM Service Protocol.

An example can be seen here:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:vm_service/vm_service_io.dart';

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  final serverUri = (await Service.getInfo()).serverUri;

  if (serverUri == null) {
    print('Please run the application with the --observe parameter!');
    return;
  }

  final isolateId = Service.getIsolateID(Isolate.current)!;
  final vmService = await vmServiceConnectUri(_toWebSocket(serverUri));
  final profile = await vmService.getAllocationProfile(isolateId, gc: true);
  
  print(profile.memoryUsage?.heapUsage);
}

List<String> _cleanupPathSegments(Uri uri) {
  final pathSegments = <String>[];
  if (uri.pathSegments.isNotEmpty) {
    pathSegments.addAll(uri.pathSegments.where(
      (s) => s.isNotEmpty,
    ));
  }
  return pathSegments;
}

String _toWebSocket(Uri uri) {
  final pathSegments = _cleanupPathSegments(uri);
  pathSegments.add('ws');
  return uri.replace(scheme: 'ws', pathSegments: pathSegments).toString();
}
```

The [`getAllocationProfile`](https://pub.dev/documentation/vm_service/latest/vm_service/VmService/getAllocationProfile.html) method takes an optional argument `gc` which is documented as:

> If `gc` is provided and is set to true, a garbage collection will be attempted before collecting allocation information. There is no guarantee that a garbage collection will be actually be performed.

So this is really the best you can do. Also, this solution will only work if the program has been started with the `--observe` parameter. So this is not something you should use for other than debugging purposes.

Comment: Not really sure about the API for that functionality.

Comment: These links are both 404'ing

Comment: @shawnblais Yes, the pages has been deleted. I don't know the reason but it was a little old and properly not maintained. I can see most of the functionality has been implemented in the Dart DevTools which seems rather nice: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools

Comment: Ah, so no way to call this from code anymore I guess? Sadness.

Comment: @shawnblais Well, it was not really possible before to trigger the GC from the code itself. But it is now with the Dart VM Service Protocol. I have added an example of how to do it today.

Comment: Seems that I cannot do that when it is compiled to AOT (using `dart compile aot my.dart`)? Is there any other ways? Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n No, not possible when compiled to AOT. Also, it should be noted that it should never be needed to manually trigger a GC for an application in production.

Comment: @julemand101 Ah... thanks

Comment: @julemand101 thanks! This works perfectly (I personally needed to trigger GC from tests in order to check that `WeakReference` clearing was handled properly).

Also note that no need to check if `serverUri` is null in tests.

Comment: Hi, how can we make "observe" in a dart test? seems that this option does not exist. thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n Not for a specific test case. You would need to execute a test suite using a Dart VM started with the observed parameter, since you cannot just start and stop the observing at runtime.

Comment: @julemand101 thanks for your reply, I have posted my scripts about doing it conveniently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72934204/4619958

Answer (score 1):

For those who wants to trigger GC in *Dart/Flutter tests* (e.g. `dart test my_file.dart`), here is my solution based on @julemand101:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:common_dart/utils/processes.dart';
import 'package:front_log/front_log.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:vm_service/vm_service.dart' hide Isolate, Log;
import 'package:vm_service/vm_service.dart' as vm_service;
import 'package:vm_service/vm_service_io.dart';

const _kTag = 'vm_services';

FutureOr<void> runTestsInVmService(
  FutureOr<void> Function(VmServiceUtil) body, {
  required String selfFilePath,
}) async {
  Log.d(_kTag, 'runInVmService selfFilePath=$selfFilePath Platform.script.path=${Platform.script.path}');

  if (Platform.script.path == selfFilePath) {
    final vmService = await VmServiceUtil.create();
    tearDownAll(vmService.dispose);
    await body(vmService);
  } else {
    test('run all tests in subprocess', () async {
      await executeProcess('dart', ['run', '--enable-vm-service', selfFilePath]);
    });
  }
}

class VmServiceUtil {
  static const _kTag = 'VmServiceUtil';

  final VmService vmService;

  VmServiceUtil._(this.vmService);

  static Future<VmServiceUtil> create() async {
    final serverUri = (await Service.getInfo()).serverUri;
    if (serverUri == null) {
      throw Exception('Cannot find serverUri for VmService. '
          'Ensure you run like `dart run --enable-vm-service path/to/your/file.dart`');
    }

    final vmService = await vmServiceConnectUri(_toWebSocket(serverUri), log: _Log());
    return VmServiceUtil._(vmService);
  }

  void dispose() {
    vmService.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> gc() async {
    final isolateId = Service.getIsolateID(Isolate.current)!;
    final profile = await vmService.getAllocationProfile(isolateId, gc: true);
    Log.d(_kTag, 'gc triggered (heapUsage=${profile.memoryUsage?.heapUsage})');
  }
}

String _toWebSocket(Uri uri) {
  final pathSegments = [...uri.pathSegments.where((s) => s.isNotEmpty), 'ws'];
  return uri.replace(scheme: 'ws', pathSegments: pathSegments).toString();
}

class _Log extends vm_service.Log {
  static const _kTag = 'vm_services';

  @override
  void warning(String message) => Log.w(_kTag, message);

  @override
  void severe(String message) => Log.e(_kTag, message);
}


Future<void> executeProcess(String executable, List<String> arguments) async {
  Log.d(_kTag, 'executeProcess start `$executable ${arguments.join(" ")}`');

  final process = await Process.start(executable, arguments);

  process.stdout.listen((e) => Log.d(_kTag, String.fromCharCodes(e)));
  process.stderr.listen((e) => Log.d(_kTag, '[STDERR] ${String.fromCharCodes(e)}'));

//  stdout.addStream(process.stdout);
//  stderr.addStream(process.stderr);

  final exitCode = await process.exitCode;
  Log.d(_kTag, 'executeProcess end exitCode=$exitCode');
  if (exitCode != 0) {
    throw Exception('Process execution failed (exitCode=$exitCode)');
  }
}
```

How to use it:

```dart
void main() {
  runTestsInVmService(
    _core,
    selfFilePath: 'path/to/my/file.dart',
  );
}

void _core(VmServiceUtil vmService) {
  test('hello', () async {
    do_something();
    await vmService.gc();
    do_another_thing();
  });
}
```