# How to monitor memory leaks in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory

I have use a recursive algorithm within my app, to accomplish certain operation which I don't wish to share. Basically the problem is that the app works fine for the first operation, but when the same operation is done twice without reloading the screen, then the app becomes slow and takes more time to process. The app recurses through a list which consists of 500 sublists. So I want to know how to study memory leaks in flutter using dart devtools and what is the best practice to carry out this operation.

I think the issue is that whenever I get the output and store it, then the memory consumption increases and hence it affects other future operations.

Comment: You can check the following link: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory

Comment: Check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62471179/5197712

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to disposed(in the dispose method of your state class) necessary objects that might remain in memory even when you don't need them anymore